# Two simple COUNT columns without subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

**1.) Data Model**

I heavily minimized the data model to the relevant parts only, here it is:

```
DOCUMENT
  id

DOCUMENT2FILE
  document_id (references DOCUMENT)
  file_id     (references FILE)

FILE
  id
  filetype_id (references FILETYPE)

FILETYPE
  id
  name
```

**2.) Demo Data**

Let's assume we have the following data (JOIN the tables and SELECT everything):

```
document.id   file.id   filetype.id   filetype.name

1             1         1             PDF
1             2         1             PDF
1             3         2             XML
1             4         2             XML

2             5         1             PDF
2             6         2             XML

3             7         1             PDF

4             8         2             XML

5             NULL      NULL          NULL
```

So there are 5 documents, each can have several files attached. Each file has one filetype (PDF or XML only).

**3.) Desired Query Result**

Now, I want to run a query, which outputs the following result set:

```
document_id   pdf_count   xml_count
1             2           2
2             1           1
3             1           0
4             0           1
5             0           0
```

**4.) Inefficient Solution**

I came up with this query, which generates exactly the desired result:

```
SELECT
    id,

    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM
         document,
         document2file,
         file,
         filetype
     WHERE document.id = document2file.document_id
     AND document2file.file_id = file.id
     AND file.filetype_id = filetype.id
     AND document.id = document_global.id
     AND filetype.name = "PDF") AS pdf_count,

     (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM
         document,
         document2file,
         file,
         filetype
     WHERE document.id = document2file.document_id
     AND document2file.file_id = file.id
     AND file.filetype_id = filetype.id
     AND document.id = document_global.id
     AND filetype.name = "XML") AS xml_count

FROM
    document document_global;
```

**5.) The Question**

This query works fine, but...

**Is there a way to do it more efficiently WITHOUT these two subqueries? Is there maybe a way to do it with COUNT, GROUP BY and HAVING only?**

I would be really happy, if someone could help me out and teach me how to be more efficient. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want conditional summation:

```
select d2f.id,
       sum(case when ft.name = 'PDF' then 1 else 0 end) as PDF_count,
       sum(case when ft.name = 'XML' then 1 else 0 end) as XML_count
from document2file d2f join
     file f
     on d2f.file_id = f.id join
     filetype ft
     on f.filetype_id = ft.id
group by d2f.id;
```

Comment: Wow, Gordon, that was very fast! And in addition to that your answer is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: Gordon is amazing. It's hard to find quicker/better answers than him.